# Powershell get lines between multiple xml tags

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm currently trying to construct a powershell script, which could read specific XML file and pull certain words. These words would be located between tags.

Currently the file would look like this. Let's call it events.xml:

```
<Computer>Hostname</Computer><Other>Random Text</Other<Other>More Random Text</Other><FilePath>notepad.exe</FilePath>
```

What I would like to do, is use Powershell script to extract words between `<Computer></Computer>` and `<FilePath></FilePath>` tags and echo them to Powershell.

So far I have this:

```
gc events.xml | % { [regex]::matches( $_ , '(?<=<Computer>)(.*?)(?=</Computer>)' ) } | select -expa value
```

Which works in a way, as it prints out a list of all the characters in between `<Computer></Computer>` tags flawlessly. But the challenge comes when trying to get a script to work so it would print out between BOTH (`<Computer></Computer>` and `<FilePath></Filepath>`) lines. So it would come out as:

Hostname
Notepad.exe

And so forth.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Any reasons to parse XML as text and not as XML?

Comment: No particular reason, just lack of knowledge. If XML parsing is easier, I'm eager to start learning on how to go forward with that method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this :

First, Load the XML target file with this :

```
$xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path(".\<name_file>.xml")
$xdoc.load($file)
$xdoc = [xml] (get-content ".\<name_file>.xml")
```

/!\ Be careful, you have to be in the good directory to use .\

Then, as you know the structure of the XML document, you should try this :

```
$Couples = $xdoc.[name_of_the_tag]
```

Select the tag above the `<Computers></Computers>` and `<FilePath></FilePath>` tags.

And then, a counter, to use it in a while loop (to develop your xml) :

```
$CouplesCount = $Couples.Count
```

In a while loop :

```
$i = 0
while($i -ne $CouplesCount ){
    $computer = $Couples.Computer
    $FilePath = $Couples.FilePath

    Write-Host $computer  
    Write-Host $FilePath 
    $i++
}
```

You should have something that prints your XML file with the values of your `<Computers></Computers>` and `<FilePath></FilePath>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me to the right direction with XML parsing.

I solved my script by doing this:

```
$xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file = resolve-path(".\events.xml")
$xdoc.load($file)
$xdoc = [xml] (get-content ".\events.xml")

$xdoc.Events.Event |

select @{ L = 'Computer';       E = { $_.System.Computer } },
       @{ L = 'FilePath';       E = { $_.UserData.RuleAndFileData.FilePath } }
```

Which resulted in a nice, clean list.

Cheers!